# KeyGenerator returning java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm for BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle, java-security

I am trying to use BouncyCastle in my Java project to generate an AES key using KeyGenerator by doing something like this :

```
KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

However this keeps returning :

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: AES for provider BC
```

I definitely made sure I have my java.security file as :

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.11=apple.security.AppleProvider
```

and bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar is under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext

In my code, I also used

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

If I try to list all the providers when running my code using Security.getProviders() , I see:

```
SUN
BC
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
Apple
```

So at this point, I am not sure what else I might have missed.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Wondering if this may have to do with JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy?  Do you have the unlimited strength jars in your directory?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: Hi neal! Yes, I am actually using Java 7 here due to a legacy repo, and I have extracted the US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html    and put them under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security

Comment: Did I miss something else? Thanks

Comment: BC 1.47 is old but even so this should work; try iterating through `Security.getProviders()` and see if it is listed there as it should be. Or, if you only need a key you don't need BC for that, you can use the standard SunJCE. @neal: AES-128 doesn't require Unlimited Policy, and anyway jce8 policy won't work on jdk7 -- you need jce7 which is missing from the archive 'platform downloads' index but can be found by site (OTN) search.

Comment: Hi dave_thompson_085,  yes I have tried to list the providers and I do see a BC show up. i have also tried calling KeyGenerator.getInstance without the BC param and it is the same error.  I could try to see if SunJCE works as a provider

Comment: I tried SunJCE, and I am getting a similar error:      java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyGenerator: com.sun.crypto.provider.AESKeyGenerator not a KeyGenerator

Answer (score 4):

Actually my bad, I think I have solved my own issue. I should also have been clearer in my question. I am running this in a Junit test and was wondering why it was failing.

Apparently, PowerMock has mocked out all the javax.crypto.* libraries and I had to tell PowerMock to ignore those libraries explicitly, and now it works properly : |

Comment: @PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.crypto.*" })